# regex with lookbehind weird behavior

Tags: java, javascript, python, regex, regex-greedy

I have been trying to resolve this for the past 2 days...

Please help me in understanding why this is happening. My intention is to just select the `<HDR>` that has a `<DTL1 val="92">.....</HDR>`

This is my regular expression

```
(?<=<HDR>).*?<DTL1\sval="3".*?</HDR>
```

And the input string is:

```
<HDR>abc<DTL1 val="1"><DTL2 val="2"></HDR><HDR><DTL1 val="92"><DTL2 val="55"></HDR><HDR><DTL1 val="3"><DTL2 val="4"></HDR>
```

But this regular expression selects

```
abc<DTL1 val="1"><DTL2 val="2"></HDR><HDR><DTL1 val="92"><DTL2 val="55"></HDR>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: could you format your input?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I have formatted the query. Thanks for telling me ...I dint know

Comment: Which regex flavor is it, Java or Python?  (It's not JavaScript, since that doesn't support lookbehinds.)  Please remove the tags that don't apply.

Answer (score 2):

A regex engine will give you always the leftmost match in a string (even if you use a non-greedy quantifier). This is exactly what you obtain.

So, a solution is to forbid the presence of another `<HDR>` in the parts described by  `.*?` that is too permissive.

You have two technics to do that, you can replace the `.*?` with:

```
(?>[^<]+|<(?!/HDR))*
```

or with:

```
(?:(?!</HDR).)*+
```

Most of the time, the first technic is more performant, but if your string contains an high density of `<`, the second way can give good results too.

The use of a [possessive quantifier](http://regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) or an [atomic group](http://regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) can reduce the number of steps to obtain a result in particular when the subpattern fails.

Example:

With the first way:

```
(?<=<HDR>)(?>[^<]+|<(?!/HDR))*<DTL1\sval="3"(?>[^<]+|<(?!/HDR))*</HDR>
```

or this variant:

```
(?<=<HDR>)(?:[^<]+|<(?!/HDR|DTL1))*+<DTL1\sval="3"(?:[^<]+|<(?!/HDR))*+</HDR>
```

With the second way:

```
(?<=<HDR>)(?:(?!</HDR).)*<DTL1\sval="3"(?:(?!</HDR).)*+</HDR>
```

or this variant:

```
(?<=<HDR>)(?:(?!</HDR|DTL1).)*+<DTL1\sval="3"(?:(?!</HDR).)*+</HDR>
```

Comment: I have tried to replace the first .*? in my regular expression with the expression that you have mentioned above. For some reason, it results in no match. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @sundar: yes, don't forget that the dot doesn't match newlines by default. To change this behavior you need to use the dotall mode.

Comment: @sundar: another thing, Even if you use a free-spacing mode to write your pattern, you can't split a token like `(?<=` with whitespaces.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: All the newlines and most of the other whitespace in the code samples were introduced when sundar used the snippet feature to format the code.  I reverted that and formatted it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: @sundar: I see what is the problem, I changed the patterns to other variants and I added examples to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Casimir et Hippolyte already gave you a couple of good solutions. I want to elaborate on a few things.

First, why your regex fails to do what you want: `(?<=<HDR>).*?` tells it to match any number of characters starting with the first character preceded by `<HDR>`, until it encounters what follows the non-greedy quantifier (`<DTL1...`). Well, the first character that's preceded by `<HDR>` is the first `a`, so it matches everything starting from there until the fixed string `<DTL1\sval="3"` is encountered.

Casimir et Hippolyte's solutions are for the generalized case, where the contents of the <HDR> tags can be anything other than nested <HDR>'s. You could also do it with a positive look-ahead:

```
(?<=<HDR>)(.(?!</HDR>))*<DTL1\sval="3".*?</HDR>
```

However, if the string is guaranteed to be in the structure shown, where the <HDR> tags only contain one or more <DTL1 val="*##*"> tags, so you know there won't be any closing tags within, you could do it more efficiently by replacing the first `.*?` with `[^/]*`:

```
(?<=<HDR>)[^/]*<DTL1\sval="3".*?</HDR>
```

A negated character class is more efficient than a zero-width assertion, and *if* you're using a negated character class, a greedy quantifier becomes more efficient than a lazy one.

Note also that by using a lookbehind to match the opening <HDR>, you're excluding it from the match, but you're including the closing </HDR>. Are you sure that's what you want? You're matching this...

```
<DTL1 val="3"><DTL2 val="4"></HDR>
```

...when presumably you want this...

```
<HDR><DTL1 val="3"><DTL2 val="4"></HDR>
```

...or this...

```
<DTL1 val="3"><DTL2 val="4">
```

So, in the fist case, don't use a lookbehind for the opening tag:

```
<HDR>(.(?!</HDR>))*<DTL1\sval="3".*?</HDR>
<HDR>[^/]*<DTL1\sval="3".*?</HDR>
```

In the second case, use a look-ahead for the closing tag:

```
(?<=<HDR>)(.(?!</HDR>))*<DTL1\sval="3".*?(?=</HDR>)
(?<=<HDR>)[^/]*<DTL1\sval="3".*?(?=</HDR>)
```

Comment: Wonderful. Your answer made my day....!!!!!Many many thanks....!!!!!I was trying to get this literally through the thanksgiving weekend......

Comment: if you waant to select this `<DTL1 val="92">.....</HDR>` block then why you gave `<DTL1\sval="3"` in your regex?

Comment: (?<=<HDR>)(.(?!</HDR>))*<DTL1\sval="3".*?</HDR> is the regular expression that I used on the input given in this question and that   matched the exact selection that I intended to make. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Well said, but one correction.  When you use the captive lookahead technique, you should put the dot *after* the lookahead.  To see why, try matching the last `<HDR>...</HDR>` element, whatever's in it.  `<HDR>(.(?!</HDR>))*</HDR>$` doesn't match because the dot isn't allowed to match the `>` before the closing `</HDR>` tag, but `<HDR>((?!</HDR>).)*</HDR>$` works.